# Use a custom class for the value of TextField does not survive across re-composition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In the code below, the `TextField` that takes a `mutableStateOf("")` works as expected: The `TextField` shows whatever I type in.

However, if the `TextField` takes `StrHolder.s` as the value. The `TextField` does not show anything I type. Why is that?

```
class StrHolder(var s: String)

Column {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
    )

    var strHolder by remember {
        mutableStateOf(StrHolder(""))
    }
    Text("My text is: ${strHolder.s}")
    TextField(
        value = strHolder.s,
        onValueChange = { strHolder.s = it },
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `mutableStateOf` to trigger recomposition, the container value should be updated, e.g. `strHolder = newValue`.

There's no way how it can know you've changed one of inner values.

`data class` (with `val`-only properties) is a great tool to be used in functional programming for such cases: copying the data will save your from such mistakes:

```
data class StrHolder(val s: String)

var strHolder by remember {
    mutableStateOf(StrHolder(""))
}
Text("My text is: ${strHolder.s}")
TextField(
    value = strHolder.s,
    onValueChange = { strHolder = strHolder.copy(s = it) },
)
```

You can find more info about state in Compose in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Compose to know about changes to your `StrHolder.s` property, you need to wrap it inside a `State`. Like this:

```kotlin
class StrHolder {
    var s by mutableStateOf("")
}
```

```kotlin
val strHolder by remember { mutableStateOf(Data()) }
TextField(
    value = strHolder.s, 
    onValueChange = { strHolder.s = it }
)
```