# How to refresh Composables in a for-loop to redraw content

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a

```
class IndexState(idx: Int) {
    var index: Int = idx
}
```

what I remeber in my Composable like:

```
val state = remember {
    IndexState(0)
}
```

So I can remember the last selected row in following column. I have a for loop to draw 10 Rows of `Text` and `Image` pairs. The Image shall be a checkmark, only visible on that row recently clicked or the initial one:

```
for (i in 0..9) {

    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .clickable {
            Logger.debug("PRE", "Index at ${state.index}")
            state.index = i
            Logger.debug("POST", "Index at ${state.index}")
        })
    {
        Text(
            text = i.toString()
        )

        if(i == state.index) {
            Icon(
                id = "Checked_$i",
                icon = R.drawable.checkbox
            )
        }
    }
}
```

According to the log cat the PRE and POST logs seem to be correct. Whenever I click a row, the new index is being stored in `state.index`. But the for loop is not being redrawn. The checkmark remains always on the initial index.

The above for loop is inside a `@Composable`. So how can I trigger the rows, so that my checkmark is refreshed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a custom class for the value of TextField does not survive across re-composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70051260/use-a-custom-class-for-the-value-of-textfield-does-not-survive-across-re-composi)

Answer (score 2):

When you call:

```
val state = remember {
    IndexState(0)
}
```

a composable will only recompose when the value provided by the code inside remember changes. But you are not changing the value. You are changing the data inside the object IndexState. The object instance itself does not change and that is what remember is observing. This is a common mistake by developers using Compose.

To change the value use `mutableStateListOf`. Also, it should be noted that any list operations like `add` will not trigger a recomposition if the object being remembered has not been initially used. Whether this is a bug in Compose or by design, I really cannot say. Seems more like bug. To fix this, you need to read the object. Usually this is not an issue because the remembered object is normally used in your composable in a location during composition that allows it to be read. But in the sample shown here, there is no place where it is read, so we need to read it by assigning it to the variable `c`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {
    val clickedItems = remember {
        mutableStateListOf<Int>()
    }

    val c = clickedItems

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        for (i in 0..9) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .requiredHeight(30.dp)
                    .clickable {
                        clickedItems.add(i)
                    }
            ) {
                if (clickedItems.contains(i)) {
                    Text(text = "$i - clicked")
                } else {
                    Text(text = i.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```